# How do i display the images my users upload without stretching it using php, mind you, the images are of different sizes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do i display the images my users upload without stretching it using php,
Now the issue is that the images are of different sizes because they are user generated images.
Now i want to display the images all in the same way they came, i mean , the ones that were uploaded in portrait and landscape should both show in the orientation in which they came, A typical example is [here](http://www.shutterstock.com/instant/#searchterm=meditation) .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use libraries like this: https://github.com/Sybio/ImageWorkshop here is the doku: http://phpimageworkshop.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use **CSS**'s `max-width` and `max-height` properties?
for example:

```
.img {
  max-width:100px;
  max-height:50px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

or is your question on how to scale them in **PHP** respecting the original `width`/`height` ratio?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have uploaded and can show the images.

just add **CSS** on the `div` your image was.

assuming your image path is on `db` and you already have the fetch `array` function

```
<?
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlQuery)
{
echo '
<div class="img">
<img src='.$record['image_path'].'>
</div>
';

}
?>
```

then add **CSS** on class `img` like:

```
.img{
height:54px;
width:54px;
}
```

the sizes depends on how large you want them.

I think this would work.

Comment: should use max-height and max-width so CSS does the resizing for u in proportion